# Making <cfmail> wait until a file is ready

Tags: coldfusion

I have a function which generates an Excel file (using ColdFusion's spreadsheet functions) and stores the result as `ReportContent`.

I need to mail that report to a group of people using `<cfmail>`:

```
<cfmail from="#From#" to="#To#" subject="#Subject#" type="html" >
    <cfmailparam content="#ReportContent#" type="application/vnd.ms-excel" file="#FileName#" >
    #Body#
</cfmail>
```

My problem is that, in testing, I found that the `<cfmail>` command would often execute before the Excel file was fully rendered, attaching instead an unusable `.tmp` file.

I tried to handle this by pausing execution for 5 seconds, giving the Excel file time to render:

```
<cfscript>
    thread = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Thread");
    thread.sleep(5000);
</cfscript>
```

This worked in most cases, but was not effective 100% of the time. I have now kicked up the delay to 15 seconds -- which works for my current tests, but I'm not convinced it is the best strategy.

Is there a way to confirm that the Excel file in `ReportContent` is fully rendered before calling `<cfmail>`?

Comment: thats worrying, i have similar thing but creating a pdf file which is then emailed, although we've not had any issues so far ...

Comment: You could incorporate the `FileExists()` function to make sure the `cfmail` command only fires after explicitly checking the expected output and extension. If it's not ready, run the check again every 5 seconds or so. You seem to have a good grasp on threading; if your only issue is timing, this would be a fix.

Comment: Are you generating the file and invoking cfmail in the same script? What are you using to save the generated report to #FileName#?

Comment: Based on my quick read of the documentation on cfmail param, I think he's attempting to use a variable as an email attachment, without actually creating the file.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk has inferred correctly (and I apologize for a lack of clarity about that detail): I am using `<cfset ReportContent = SpreadsheetReadBinary( sObj ) >` to write the spreadsheet object to `ReportContent`.

Comment: ill add on to @TRose. You can have the file go to a directory, and after it  exists, mail it, then delete it. Unless you need to keep the docs.

Comment: @JoeDeRose - Nah, you were clear. I just totally overlooked the "content" variable, duh! ;-)

Comment: That's odd. Are you creating the spreadsheet in a thread?

Comment: I was going to say you could split threads and then join when done, but really, it shouldn't be mailing before the code before it is complete. Need to see the code before the <cfmail>

Answer (score 0):

Use a named lock like this, and see if it helps:

```
<cflock name="some_preferably_unique_lock_name" type="exclusive" timeout="60">
<!--- code that creates and writes the Excel file to disk --->
</cflock>

<cflock name="same_preferably_unique_lock_name" type="exclusive" timeout="60">
<!--- code that mails the Excel file as attachment --->
</cflock>
```